# How to change verbose_name_plural in Django dynamic models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using dynamic Django models, and sometimes dealing with them is not as simple as dealing with regular models! In my case, each model has a different name once they are created, but they all inherit from the same model. So their plural names should also be different. Is there a way to change the `verbose_name_plural` for dynamic models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, in case anyone has this problem. This goes in the Meta of the attributes of your dynamic model like this:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = name
model = type(name, (ModelName,), {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta})
```